# addEventlistener in jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my image slider code onclick event was not working on android tablet .I am using Jquery lib.when I  added following code ,

```
var clickEventType=((document.ontouchstart!==null)?'click':'touchstart');
$("#myImageFlow").bind(clickEventType, function( e ) {
    $(this).addEventListener( 'touchstart', touchStart, false);
}); 
//custom function handler for event                  
function touchStart(event){
     event.preventDefault();

};
```

this code make make my slider respond ontouch event  but in Inspect console i am getting error

**Error::**

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addEventListener'

because of this error some of functionality is not working ??

Comment: may be try this : `$(this).get(0).addEventListener( 'touchstart', touchStart, false);`

Comment: Why are you trying to add an event listener from _inside_ another event handler? The `.bind(clickEventType...` code may (depending on the preceding line) have just added a `'touchstart'` handler, and then you're trying to add another?

Comment: @nnnnnn my image slider onclick was not working on android tab so i tried adding this way. .bind() only works if i alert something ..

Comment: @Cherniv  i tried ur suggestion not working ,

Comment: @alex my question !!!!

Answer (score 0):

use `.on()`

```
$(this).on('touchstart', touchStart);
```

you are getting that error because `.addEventListener` is not a jquery method

Comment: @pXL just wanted to know, inside `.on(a, b, c)`, first parameter **a** is for the event, second **b** is for the handler, what is the third parameter `c` for?? In your case `false`??